# IPv6 Doesn't Route Outside Of Libvirt Network

Tags: ubuntu, networking, routing, ipv6

I have VM which has a single interface that itself only has IPv6 available from libvirt's dnsmasq:

```
2: enp1s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 52:54:00:49:0c:72 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet6 2600:1700:7d0:97a0::1a1/128 scope global dynamic noprefixroute 
       valid_lft 2727sec preferred_lft 2727sec
    inet6 fe80::5054:ff:fe49:c72/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

I can ping the gateway:

```
root@ipv6-test:~# ping -c3 2600:1700:7d0:97a0::1
PING 2600:1700:7d0:97a0::1(2600:1700:7d0:97a0::1) 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 2600:1700:7d0:97a0::1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.287 ms
64 bytes from 2600:1700:7d0:97a0::1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.297 ms
64 bytes from 2600:1700:7d0:97a0::1: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.307 ms

--- 2600:1700:7d0:97a0::1 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2026ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.287/0.297/0.307/0.008 ms
```

The Hypervisor can ping IPv6 internet addresses:

```
 root /var/lib/libvirt/dnsmasq> ping6 -c3 2001:67c:1562::16
PING 2001:67c:1562::16(2001:67c:1562::16) 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 2001:67c:1562::16: icmp_seq=1 ttl=52 time=26.3 ms
64 bytes from 2001:67c:1562::16: icmp_seq=2 ttl=52 time=26.4 ms
64 bytes from 2001:67c:1562::16: icmp_seq=3 ttl=52 time=25.9 ms

--- 2001:67c:1562::16 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2003ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 25.918/26.201/26.363/0.200 ms
```

but the VM fails:

```
root@ipv6-test:~# ping6 -c3 2001:67c:1562::16
PING 2001:67c:1562::16(2001:67c:1562::16) 56 data bytes

--- 2001:67c:1562::16 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 2051ms
```

IPv6 forward *seems* to be enabled on the hypervisor:

```
 root /var/lib/libvirt/dnsmasq> for x in /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/*/forwarding; do echo "$x $(cat $x)"; done
/proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/all/forwarding 1
/proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/default/forwarding 1
/proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/enp4s0/forwarding 0
/proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/lo/forwarding 1
/proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/virbr0/forwarding 1
/proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/virbr0-nic/forwarding 1
/proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/virbr1/forwarding 1
/proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/virbr1-nic/forwarding 1
/proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/virbr2/forwarding 1
/proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/virbr2-nic/forwarding 1
/proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/vnet0/forwarding 1
/proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/vnet10/forwarding 1
/proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/vnet11/forwarding 1
/proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/vnet12/forwarding 1
/proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/vnet1/forwarding 1
/proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/vnet2/forwarding 1
/proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/vnet3/forwarding 1
/proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/vnet4/forwarding 1
/proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/vnet5/forwarding 1
/proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/vnet6/forwarding 1
/proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/vnet7/forwarding 1
/proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/vnet8/forwarding 1
/proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/vnet9/forwarding 1
/proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/wlp5s0/forwarding 1
```

The routing table that gets populated by DHCP uses a `fe80` address for the default gateway, but I don't know enough about IPv6 to really know if this is incorrect:

```
root@ipv6-test:~# ip -6 route
::1 dev lo proto kernel metric 256 pref medium
2600:1700:7d0:97a0::/64 dev enp1s0 proto ra metric 100 expires 3380sec pref medium
fe80::/64 dev enp1s0 proto kernel metric 256 pref medium
default via fe80::5054:ff:fe8b:5ea5 dev enp1s0 proto ra metric 100 expires 1580sec mtu 1500 pref medium
```

At this point, I'm not entirely sure what to check. I'm assuming it's the IPv6 portion that's the difficulty since I don't know if gateways work the same way or follow the same numbering conventions.

**EDIT:**
fwiw I can also ping the IPv6 addresses of other interfaces on the hypervisor:

```
root@ipv6-test:~# ping 2600:1700:7d0:97a0:50f:4c0e:8ced:fe20
PING 2600:1700:7d0:97a0:50f:4c0e:8ced:fe20(2600:1700:7d0:97a0:50f:4c0e:8ced:fe20) 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 2600:1700:7d0:97a0:50f:4c0e:8ced:fe20: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.332 ms
64 bytes from 2600:1700:7d0:97a0:50f:4c0e:8ced:fe20: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.322 ms
64 bytes from 2600:1700:7d0:97a0:50f:4c0e:8ced:fe20: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.364 ms
64 bytes from 2600:1700:7d0:97a0:50f:4c0e:8ced:fe20: icmp_seq=4 ttl=64 time=0.261 ms
^C
--- 2600:1700:7d0:97a0:50f:4c0e:8ced:fe20 ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 4 received, 0% packet loss, time 3004ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.261/0.319/0.364/0.037 ms
```

Also, I did a packet trace and it looks like the source IP address (which is now `fd7d:844d:3e17:f3ae::1a1/128` due to my testing) isn't being NAT'd. I'm not sure if this means that the return traffic isn't being routed back to the hypervisor from the internet.

Comment: IPv4 gateway addresses are internal 192... , 10.... and so on. Since the fe80 addresses are LAN internal then that much looks okay.  You could check this : https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/check-for-ipv6-support-in-linux-kernel/

Comment: @StephenBoston yeah the IPv6 portion seems to be working alright in the kernel. It's just something being misconfigured. I'm now assuming that it's not masquerading the source IP even though the network is configured to NAT clients. I read online that IPv6 is supposed to make NAT obsolete in favor of globally available addressing but I don't know what that means regarding what I should be expecting to see or what addresses I should be using in the DHCP pool.

Comment: @A.B I did after I posted just to test, but `enp4s0` isn't even plugged in. The only internet-facing interface on this machine is `wlp5s0`. The behavior didn't change after enabling forwarding.

Comment: For clarity, the `enp1s0` in the OP is the VM's interface.